# Convert compress functions from Python to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gzip, zlib

I have functions in Python for compression and decompression of a string (bytearray):

```
def compress_message(data):
    compressor = zlib.compressobj(-1, zlib.DEFLATED, 31, 8, zlib.Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY)
    compressed_data = compressor.compress(data)
    compressed_data += compressor.flush()
    return compressed_data


def decompress_message(compressed_data):
    return zlib.decompress(compressed_data, wbits=31)
```

I need to convert these functions to kotlin, so I can use them in my mobile app. So far I tried this:

```
fun String.zlibCompress(): ByteArray {
    val input = this.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
    val output = ByteArray(input.size * 4)
    val compressor = Deflater().apply {
        setLevel(-1)
        setInput(input)
        finish()
    }
    val compressedDataLength: Int = compressor.deflate(output)
    return output.copyOfRange(0, compressedDataLength)
}
```

However, it gives totally different results for example for string `abcdefghijklmnouprstuvwxyz`:

```
Python: 1f8b080000000000000a4b4c4a4e494d4bcfc8cccacec9cdcb2f2d282a2e292d2bafa8ac0200c197b2d21a000000
Kotlin: 789c4b4c4a4e494d4bcfc8cccacec9cdcb2f2d282a2e292d2bafa8ac020090b30b24
```

Is there any way, how can I modify the kotlin code, so it gives same result as Python?

Thanks for your replies. <3

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.  Also, since this is not a python problem, then python tag is incorrect, please edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `31` parameter in the Python code is requesting a *gzip* stream, not a zlib stream. In Kotlin, you are generating a zlib stream. (zlib is described in RFC 1950, gzip in RFC 1952.)

It does not appear that Java's `Deflater` (spelled wrong) class has that option. It does have a `nowrap` option that gives raw deflate compressed data, around which you can construct your own gzip wrapper, using the RFC to see how.

By the way, the results are not "totally different". You have gzip and zlib wrappers around exactly the same raw deflate compressed data: `4b4c`...`0020`.

Comment: Thank you for the information that it's a gzip. I found some examples on the Internet and code that works for me is this `fun String.gzipCompress(): ByteArray { val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream() GZIPOutputStream(bos).bufferedWriter(Charsets.UTF_8).use { it.write(this) } var ba = bos.toByteArray() ba[9] = 10 return ba` I don't know why it has 0 instead of 10 on byte 9, however the rest is the same so it works fine.

Comment: `ba[9]`, the tenth byte in the header, identifies the operating system. Nothing that I know of makes any use of that information, so changing it is irrelevant.